# Return enum type based on string value in swift?

Tags: enums, swift

I'm trying to do the following in a playground to assign an enum type based on a string, but getting an error in the changeType function. How can I get this to work properly?

```
enum TransactionType {
    case purchase,charge
    case deposit,payment

    func description() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .purchase:
            return "purchase"
        case .charge:
            return "charge"
        case .deposit:
            return "deposit"
        case .payment:
            return "payment"
        }
    }

    func typeFromString(value:String) -> TransactionType   {
        switch value {
        case "charge":
            return .charge
        case "deposit":
            return .deposit
        case "payment":
            return .payment
        default:
            return .purchase
        }
    }
}

class Tester {
    var transactionType = TransactionType.purchase

    func changeType() {
        transactionType = TransactionType.typeFromString("charge")
    }
}

var tester = Tester()
print(tester.transactionType.description())

tester.changeType()
print(tester.transactionType.description())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simpler than you think:

```
enum TransactionType : String {
    case purchase = "purchase", charge = "charge"
    case deposit = "deposit", payment = "payment"
}

class Tester {
    var transactionType = TransactionType.purchase

    func changeType() {
        transactionType = TransactionType.fromRaw("charge")!
    }
}

var tester = Tester()
print(tester.transactionType.toRaw())

tester.changeType()
print(tester.transactionType.toRaw())
```

The trick is to set a raw value of `String` type, which defines the type associated to each enum case.

More info [Raw Values in Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_228)

Comment: I was wondering why I couldn't do the raw string values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `typeFromString` method as static in order to  avoid complications with optional values. After all, it just contains constants anyway. Simply add the word `static` before the `func` definition.

```
static func typeFromString(value:String) -> TransactionType   {
```